# Ethereum RPC equivalent of bitcoind's listsinceblock

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, blocks

Is it something have go-ethereum or parity similar as listsinceblock? Because iterate step by step from chosen block number/hash to actual `eth.blockNumber` will be very expensive operation.